# Get connecting client info with tcp-accept?

Tags: tcp, racket

An echo server that runs on port 12321 is simple enough:

```
(define listener (tcp-listen 12321))
(define (mk-server)
  (let echo-server ()
    (define-values (in out) (tcp-accept listener))
    (thread (λ () (copy-port in out)
              (close-output-port out)))
    (echo-server)))
```

The [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/tcp.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ftcp..rkt%29._tcp-abandon-port%29%29) has a lot of functions for `tcp-`whatever, but they all return `boolean?` or `tcp-listener?`; I can't figure out which one will give me the connecting client's IP address.

The [super simple socket server example tutorial](http://docs.racket-lang.org/more/index.html?q=tcp#%28part.__.Hello_.World__.Server%29) also only mentions handling data sent by the client.

The port `in` in the above example will have all the data the client sent (headers, etc), but won't contain metadata *about* the client.

For example, in [Factor](http://factorcode.org), the `accept` method of `<server>` objects returns a two-way-stream for writing / reading, and a tuple of data:

```
T{ inet4 { host "127.0.0.1" } { port 36150 } }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that you use the port `in` to read data sent from the client and that data written to `out` is automatically sent to the client.

If I read the documentation correctly, one of these:

```
(tcp-addresses in)
(tcp-addresses out)
```

should give you the client address.

Comment: Anything I try to do with `(tcp-addresses in)` gives `expected number of values not received
  expected: 1
  received: 2
  values...:`, which I don't understand -- it wants 1 arg, I gave it 1

Comment: @cat Try `(tcp-addresses in #f)` and `(tcp-addresses out #f)` instead.

Comment: Same error -- it's not the number of args it's getting that's the problem, it's the return value, but doing `(list (tcp-addresses in #f))` also gives an error.

Comment: Ah!. Use  `(define-values (val1 val2) (tcp-addresses in))` to receive two values.

Comment: If you were curious about the application: [A simple TCP server](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77467/46231)

Comment: Golfing!  Tips:  `~a` is short than `number->string` and `(newline out)` is shorter than `(write #\n out)`.

Comment: Thank you! You should post those as an answer here : [Tips for golfing in Racket / Scheme](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77129/tips-for-golfing-in-racket-scheme) :D